# How can I filter a specific object? (not a String)

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to filter my bookList for searchView.

When I filter my bookList I want to refresh my RecylerView.
I know how to filter a String with searchView but I can't filter a specific object.

Here is my RecylerAdapter:

```
    class  BookHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder( itemView ) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyler_row,parent,false)
        return BookHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookHolder, position: Int) {




        holder.itemView.isim.text = bookList[position].kitapismi
        holder.itemView.aciklama.text = bookList[position].kitapaciklama
        holder.itemView.recyler_email.text = bookList[position].kullaniciemail
        Picasso.get().load(bookList[position].gorselurl).into(holder.itemView.recyler_image)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context,BookDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("bookIsmi",bookList[position].kitapismi)
            intent.putExtra("bookAciklama",bookList[position].kitapaciklama)
            intent.putExtra("bookImage",bookList[position].gorselurl)
            intent.putExtra("email",bookList[position].kullaniciemail)
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }


    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return bookList.size
    }





}
```

Here is my Book.kt

```
package com.ahmettarik.boorrow

import java.util.*

    data class Book(var kullaniciemail: String?
    , var kitapaciklama: String?
    , var kitapismi: String?
    , var gorselurl: String? ) {

    }
```

Here is my activity_books.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rec"
    tools:context=".BooksActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_book"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:queryBackground="@null"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you first need to figure out what the search view is filtering "on". I'm sorry I don't understand your book model all that much, so let's take a simpler example.  Image this as your data class:

```
data class Person(
    val firstName: String = "",
    val lastName: String = "",
    val age: Int = 0
)
```

Here we have described a Person object with a few fields. In a RecyclerView implementation (like you have above) we could imagine a `List<Person>` being displayed to the user. If we had a search bar at the top of the screen, and wanted the user to be able to filter the results by name, we could run this code:

```
val userInput: String = "Steven" // this would come from the search bar UI
val filteredList: List<Person> = listOfPeople.filter {
    it.firstName.contains(userInput)
}
```

the above code will filter a list by a particular attribute on the `Person` class. We could enhance this code to allow for a last name check as well like so:

```
val userInput: String = "Steven" // this would come from the search bar UI
val filteredList: List<Person> = listOfPeople.filter {
    it.firstName.contains(userInput) || it.lastName.contains(userInput)
}
```

This makes use of Kotlin's functional programming capabilities when working with a collection (in this case, a list of data).

The `filter` function will return a new list of data where the code executing inside of the lambda returns true.  So the end result of `filteredList` would be a `List<Person>` where everyone's first name or last name would contain the word "Steven".  The list would be empty if no `Person` in the list satisfied that criteria.

Comment: sorry bro ı didnt understand your answer; by the way my Book.kt data class in english like this; 


package com.ahmettarik.boorrow

import java.util.*

    data class Book(var userEmail: String?
    , var bookDescription: String?
    , var bookName: String?
    , var ımageUrl: String? ) {

    }

ı want to just filter bookName

Comment: @mythredd Please take your time to read the answer. It's pretty clearly explained. [You can also read the documentation on filtering](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html).

Comment: @m0skit0 ı read it two times really ı didnt understand

Comment: @mythredd What is you don't understand exactly?

Comment: tell me how can ı use it on my code? @m0skit0

Comment: @mythredd I think you can figure out that by yourself.

Comment: @mythredd your code would look something like:
`listOfBooks.filter {
    it.bookName.contains(userInput)
}`

Comment: @DMP bro ı dont know this code is need to where